# If we weaken Polignac's conjecture to an existential claim, can it be proved?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Polignac's conjecture (unproved) states that, for any integer $k \geq 1$, there exist infinitely many $p$ such that $p$ and $p+2k$ are both prime. Suppose that we weaken the consequent to require only that, for all such $k$,  there exists at least one $p$ such that $p$ and $p+2k$ are both prime. Has this been proved, or studied? If not, then that raises the question: "What is the smallest $k$ for which no pair of prime $p,p+2k$ is known?" (There is also the stronger conjecture, for all such $k$, there is a prime *gap* of size $2k$.)

Comment: For the second question I would guess roughly in the range of $10^{15}$ to $10^{20}$.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A020483 is "Least prime $p$ such that $p+2n$ is also prime." A comment there reads, "It is conjectured that $a(n)$ always exists. $a(n)$ has been computed for $n < 5 \times 10^{11}$, with largest value $a(248281210271) = 3307$." Some links there may be of interest.

Comment: Pomignac conjecture actually deals with consecutive primes of difference $2k$.